# How to evaluate Jmeter readings of a Load Test?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have written a Jmeter script in which I am calling some APIs of my test environment and capturing the results in Summary Report Listener.
Now what I observed is for the same build and same environment with same number of users the readings are different as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]
[image]
Can any one help me in how to conclude these readings or am I doing anything wrong

Answer (score 2):

I don't think running the "test" with 2 users and 1 iteration (or vice versa) can give you the results you can "evaluate" and/or "conclude" (whatever it means)

If you're looking for the meaning of the numbers check out [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) and [Understanding Your Reports: Part 1 - What are KPIs?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-kpis-part-1-what-are-kpis) articles.

If you're looking for the reason of results differences - you should look at the [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) which is attached to your application (if it is), if not - re-run your test against the application with [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) telemetry attached - this way you will identify the differences between processing JMeter requests on the server side.

And last but not the least, I would recommend running your test with increased number of users/iterations as single request response time may vary depending on different factors including operating system, routers, weather, sunspots, etc. and look at i.e. 90 [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I tried running the tests with more users and I am matching the Average & 90%Line response time but then also I get difference sometimes more than +-5%. I will ask dev to look whether we have any APM tool attached and check what is wrong